# What would be the equivalent to "feature completeness" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

What would be the equivalent to "feature completeness" in Spanish?

Reading an excerpt of this book "The agile samurai", which I've found navigating [this site](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com),
I've found this concept: "feature completeness", which is related to "scope".

I would like to know how to translate it into Spanish.

What I've come up so far is something like "Completitud de las características", but it does not sounds good in Spanish. As this is related to the scope of the system, and it is in the context of determine what are we willing to give, my best approach was "Alcance funcional".

Comment: Welcome to our site. We're not a translation service, although we are happy to *help* with learning the Spanish language. As such, we require that all translation questions show that you have attempted your own translation first, then we will help you improve. Can you show us what you have come up with on your own?

Comment: Hi Flimzy, thanks for your comment. What I've come up so far is something like "Completitud de las características", but it does not sounds good in spanish. As this is related to the scope of the system, and it is in the context of determine what are we willing to give, my best approach was "Alcance funcional"

Comment: Thanks for adding that information. I have re-opened the question.  I hope you receive an informative answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

To me, and based on the context, it sounds like the progress of the tasks you have in an Agile-driven project. In this context, I would just call it "avance".

If I had to particularly refer to how complete are the features of a system, i.e. how much progress we've made regarding the implementation of features of a system, I would refer to that as "completitud de las funcionalidades".

"Alcance funcional", or just "alcance" is how we usually translate "scope".

Some words are a PITA to use in their Spanish equivalents, and we use the English counterpart most of the time. I have never heard anyone here saying "burndown" in Spanish.

Comment: Thanks Carlos, as you said, no one says "burndown" in spanish, but "feature completeness" is not such a common expressión. About scope, that's correct, "alcance funcional" is a good expression. I'm still not sure about "avance" as something that can be given or that can be relaxed.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot seem to come up with a literal translation, so I thought of the best way to express the concept, and my choice would be:

> Funcionalidad completada

Now this doesn't work as a noun (I have never heard the term completitud used in a real life scenario) but it expresses clearly that the features (=funcionalidad, which despite not being an exact translation conveys roughly the same concept when talking about software) are complete

Comment: This seems to get close, but "completada" is a participle, and still make some noise on my ears.

Comment: "Funcionalidad completa" then, maybe?

Comment: how does it sounds? "Completitud de la funcionalidad"

Comment: I guess that's the most accurate, but I can say I have never ever heard the word "completitud" used, at least in Mexico, so it might be unfamiliar, if understandable, to many.

Comment: I agree with you, I've just heard that word just a couple of times, but I can't find a better expresion... yet

Comment: Perhaps instead of "completitud" you could use "plenitud".

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably say it as 'funciones cumplidas' (as in 'met', 'fulfilled', 'completed', 'complied with', etc...)

Comment: I like it too, but I would make a subtle change, what about "funcionalidades cumplidas". "Funciones" means somehting like "routines" in software languaje, and we're talking about system/user requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If by "feature completeness" you refer to the ability of a distributed work system to maintain a central version of the software which prevents cross locks among teams, you can use:

> integridad funcional.

Comment: I don't think that's what "feature completeness" means.  To me, feature completeness means "All the necessary features have been added to the product. All that remains now is to add polish and do bug fixes."

Comment: After reading the other answers, I really do not understand why the downvote.

Comment: Sorry about that, my bad. I think "integridad" does not apply, it is about having something fully completed, half complete or not completed at all, but definitively it is not about integrity.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest this

> plenitud de rasgos

Comment: I don't think this would make any sense to a programmer

Comment: I agree with @spiral, those words are not familiar for the software people